# Make different lists from list

Tags: qt, qlist

I use `Qt` and `C++`, I have a list  `(QList<int>)`

```
list<<1<<3<<4<<5<<9<<22<<32<<45
```

I want to make this

If user enter 4 I want to make this;

```
list1<<1<<3<<4<<5

list2<<9<<22<<32<<45
```

If user enter 3, I want to divide 3 lists etc.. How can I do this?

Comment: And what happens if he enters 5 or 2?

Comment: I divide 5 list if he enters 5, I mean if user enters x, I divide x lists.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below. I have not tested it , but i might give you an idea. Remember to
`#include <QtAlgorithms>` too.

```
read x;

QVector<QList<QString> > vectorOfLists;

bool continueLoop = true;
while (continueLoop)
{
 QList<QString> temp(x);
 if (list.count () > x)
 {

    qCopy(list.begin(), list.begin()+x, temp.begin());
    list.erase (list.begin(), list.begin()+x);
 }
 else
 {
   qCopy(list.begin(), list.end(), temp.begin());
   continueLoop = false;

 }
  //Add list to collection
  vectorOfLists.append (temp);
}
```